# Showing... Is not a static member of 'classname' error in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7

showing some error that the method is not a static memeber of class.

```
    parsejson.cpp:96: error: 'QList<PointstableResult> ParseJson::parsePointsTableData' is not a static member of 'class ParseJson'
```

but i have declared it in my header file  "pasejson.h"

```
   static QList<PointstableResult*> parsePointsTableData(QString);
```

but still showing the error. If Somebody knows what I might be doing wrong, it would be a great help

Comment: How do you call this function? Have you declared it as member of the `ParseJson` class?

Comment: yes I have called it as a member
        QList<PointstableResult> ParseJson::parsePointsTableData(jsonPointsString){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have called `QList<PointstableResult> ParseJson::parsePointsTableData`, but the declaration is: `QList<PointstableResult*> parsePointsTableData` (note the pointer type!)